# Installing Acrobat Flash with windows installer

Tags: windows-installer, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment, setuptools

I'm trying to add Acrobate Flash installer to my application setup project as pre request .
I made a Bootstrapper package of the Flash installer and put it on the visual studio sdk folder , then I can see it in the Pre requests dialog. But this doesn't help , when I run the installer , it install my app without Flash .

Any suggestion . 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the prerequisite configuration is incorrect. What detection criteria did you use for it? Usually a file or registry entry installed by the prerequisite is the best approach.